# Getting all review requests from Review Board Python Web API

Tags: python, review-board

I would like to get the information about all reviews from my server. That's my code that I used to achieve my goal.

```
from rbtools.api.client import RBClient
client = RBClient('http://my-server.net/')
root = client.get_root()
reviews = root.get_review_requests()
```

The variable `reviews` contains just 25 review requests (I expected much, much more). What's even stranger I tried something a bit different

```
count = root.get_review_requests(counts_only=True)
```

Now `count.count` is equal to 17164. How can I extract the rest of my reviews? I tried to check the official documentation but I haven't found anything connected to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/webapi/2.0/resources/review-request-list/#webapi2.0-review-request-list-resource), `counts_only` is only a Boolean flag that indicates following:

`If specified, a single count field is returned with the number of results, instead of the results themselves.`

But, what you could do, is to provide it with `status`, so:

```py
count = root.get_review_requests(counts_only=True, status='all')
```

should return you all the requests.

Keep in mind that I didn't test this part of the code locally. I referred to their repo test example -> https://github.com/reviewboard/rbtools/blob/master/rbtools/utils/tests/test_review_request.py#L643 and the documentation link posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [pagination](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.7/webapi/2.0/resources/review-list/#GET) (unfortunately I can't provide exact code without ability to reproduce your question):

> The maximum number of results to return in this list. By default, this is 25. There is a hard limit of 200; if you need more than 200 results, you will need to make more than one request, using the “next” pagination link.

Looks like [pagination helper class](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/3.0/extending/coderef/python/reviewboard.hostingsvcs.utils.paginator/) also available.

If you want to get 200 results you may set `max_results`:

```py
requests = root.get_review_requests(max_results=200)
```

Anyway [HERE](https://bminard.github.io/2016/03/review-board-rbtools-example) is a good example how to iterate over results.

Also I don't recommend to get all `17164` results by one request even if it possible. Because total data of response will be huge (let's say if size one a result is 10KB total size will be more than 171MB)